# Azure Policy to turn Firewall on

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-data-lake, azure-policy

There is a requirement where I need to write a policy to turn Firewall ON for DataLake Store. this policy should be written in JSON and need to deploy on Azure.

Anyone, who can help me on JSON part.

Answer (score 0):

To enable firewall when creating the DataLake Store , you could refer to my sample policy, it works fine on my side.

```
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts"
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts/firewallState",
        "equals": "Disabled"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Firewall Template. Actually, i need to turn the firewall on, so I need to write json for that. It will look like below,

{
  "if": {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts/firewallRules"
            },
 "then": {
  "effect": "Append",
  "details": {
   
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: It will not turn on the firewall. It will just validate status of the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Append** mode in effect to change the value.

```
{
   "if": {
      "field": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts/firewallState",
      "equals": "Disabled"
   },
   "then": {
      "effect": "append",
      "details": [
         {
            "field": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts/firewallState",
            "value": "Enabled"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```